# About iOS sdk sample example which can sync with facebook event

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to develop iphone calendar app which can sync with facebook events. Im not able to understand from where should I start. Can you suggest me some ways to start with?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all develop calender using this link: `https://github.com/klazuka/Kal`
This is similar to iPhone in built calendar & then display event using this with in your app.

Comment: I have already used kal in my project. But I want to sync with facebook event. Please help.